# Gcm subscribe on topics in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to subscribe the users in specific topics according to their preferences. I can apply the topics preferences when the application start in the `device.ready()` using this:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
  android: {
    senderID: "872486308701",
    topics: myTopics
  }
});
```

but i need to do it in real time, when the user is using the application. [Android native gcm topic subscribe method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmPubSub.html#subscribe(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

**EDIT:**

If I do this, will it work?

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
  android: {
    senderID: "872486308701",
    topics: ['foo']
  }
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

push.unregister(function() {
  console.log('success');
}, function() {
  console.log('error');
});

var push = PushNotification.init({
  android: {
    senderID: "872486308701",
    topics: ['foo','bar','baz']
  }
});
```

Comment: To be sure the client unregisters from the topic, write:
`push.unregister(function() {
  console.log('success');
}, function() {
  console.log('error');
},
["/topics/foo"]);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `PushNotification.init()` anytime in your code, given `deviceReady` event already fired, not just in `device.ready()`. And you can do this multiple times.

Note, in order to change the topic of the user, you first need to call `push.unregister(successclb,errorclb,["topics/foo","topics/bar"])` before you subscribe to a different topic.

Comment: I need to call `push.unregister()` before `PushNotification.init()`? I need to call `push.off()` and `push.on()` to reset the listeners?

Comment: Due to a lack of any `unregisterTopic()` you need to unregister to get rid of the old topics. If you don't call `unregister` with the current registered topic and init again, both topics will be registered to the client.

Comment: When I call `PushNotification.init()` again the app stop receiving messages.

Comment: do you call it with the same parameters? you need to provide all information again (senderId etc.). Any error in the callback?

Comment: I am getting a similar problem that I can't seem to fix. Please can you look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616067/does-the-phonegap-plugin-push-plugin-have-pubsub-functionality