# Push Notifications in Ionic 2 with the Pub/Sub Model

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am using the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin to do Push Notifications in an Ionic 2 Chat App.

I've implemented it according to the [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md), and it works, but only on the same device. i.e. it sends a notification to the phone if you supply its `device token`.

My issue is for a chat app, I need a **PubSub** model. So that a user can publish to a topic and another user can subscribe to that topic even if they are on different decices.

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md), it seems to be possible. See `android.topics` and `ios.topics`.

> android.topics    array   []  Optional. If the array contains one or more
>   strings each string will be used to subscribe to a GcmPubSub topic.

So I try the following:

Javascript Client:

**publish**

```
    let push = Push.init({
      android: {
        senderID: "xxxxxxxx",
        topics: ['foo']
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: false,
        sound: "true",
        topics: ['foo']
      },
      windows: {}
    });

push.on('registration', (data) => {
  // call the Java Server
  let promise: Promise<string> = this.notificationService.push(data.registrationId, 'This is a test message from Ionic Chat');
  promise.then((data) => {

  });
});
```

Java Server:

```
try {
    System.out.println("NotificationService: device_token: "+device_token);
    logger.info("NotificationService: device_token: "+device_token);
    // Prepare JSON containing the GCM message content. What to send and where to send.
    JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
    jData.put("title", "This is title");
    jData.put("message", message);
    jGcmData.put("to", device_token);  // <===== is this the problem???? it is the data.registrationId from the client
    // What to send in GCM message.
    jGcmData.put("data", jData);
    // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
    URL url = new URL("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Send GCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Javascript Client:

**Subscribe**

```
    let push = Push.init({
      android: {
        senderID: "xxxxxxxx",
        topics: ['foo']
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: false,
        sound: "true",
        topics: ['foo']
      },
      windows: {}
    });

    push.on('notification', (data) => {

    });
```

It works on the same device, but it doesn't work if the `publisher` and `subscriber` are on different devices.

I think the problem may be that even though another user is subscribed to the topic I publish to, it is still only publishing to the `data.registrationId` (Device Token).

See the following line on the Java Server:

```
jGcmData.put("to", device_token);
```

**Question**

Does anyone know how to make it send to all subscribers on that topic?

I think the answer is [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/):

```
"to": "/topics/foo-bar",
```

But how should this be formatted for multiple topics? (that's just one topic `foo-bar`)

Answer (score 0):

Need to Change the Java Server to send to the topic instead of the device:

```
jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/"+topics);
```

see: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/