# implement Push Notifications in Ionic 2 with the Pub/Sub Model

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Hi this is a duplicate of the question at

[Push Notifications in Ionic 2 with the Pub/Sub Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616067/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-with-the-pub-sub-model)

i have already implemented push notifications following this article >
https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.xvoeao59a

what i want is to be able to send notifications to users when some events take place in the app like chat or booking or new job post.

how to go further , this is my first app.

Comment: Do you have your ionic application linked to a backend of some sort (f.e. Java REST API) ?

Comment: no, i am using firebase as the database and file storage

Comment: @Ivaro18 would backend be required for server setup code ?

Comment: Dont know but thats how I do it so cant help you now :D

Comment: i am learning to do , if you could tell how to proceed could learn :D

Comment: Its also explained in their guide you mentioned (at the bottom - java code) i just converted it to kotlin and it worked

Comment: where that java code has to go ? in a hosted server or localhost ? or it has to be added to ionic somewhere

Comment: I myself hace it on an external server so it can be reached from everywhere, if you only want to push from your pc you could do localhost. Reason i chose external was because if I create a notification from my app, it immediately sends a push notification to all devices from anywhere in the world

Comment: For testing you can use localhost

Comment: okay, i am starting to understand, as for inside ionic how do i call for a notification to be sent once the event occurs ? can you share an example .... for example i want to send a push notification to all every time a new job is posted.

Comment: I'll show you in 1 hour approx. am in public transport atm (will post as an answer to improve formatting)

Comment: that would be great help .... waiting for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE: code is almost exactly the same as the tutorial, Java has only been converted to Kotlin*

This is my acutal ionic side code (on login page). The `push.on('registration')` will be fired when the user opens the app, the variable `this.device_id` will later (on succesfull login) be sent to my Kotlin REST API so I know the device_id and have coupled it to a user. This way  you can send targeted push notifications.

If you send a push notification from Kotlin (code shown below, looks a bit like Java), the (always open, even opens after startup) connection to Google  will send your device (defined by the `device_id` a message with the notification data (title, message, etc.) after which your device will recognize the `senderID` and match it to use your ionic application.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      let push = Push.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "1234567890"
        },
        ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: false,
          sound: "true"
        },
        windows: {}
      });

      //TODO - after login
      push.on('registration', (data) => {
        this.device_id = data.registrationId;
      }); 

      push.on('notification', (data) => {
        console.log('message', data.message);
        let self = this;
        //if user using app and push notification comes
        if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
          // if application open, show popup
          let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: data.title,
            message: data.message,
            buttons: [{
              text: 'Negeer',
              role: 'cancel'
            }, {
              text: 'Bekijk',
              handler: () => {
                //TODO: Your logic here
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventsPage, {message: data.message});
              }
            }]
          });
          confirmAlert.present();
        } else {
          //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
          //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventsPage, {message: data.message});
          console.log("Push notification clicked");
        }
      });
      push.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
      });

    });
  }
```

Kotlin code (converted from the Java example, basically the same

```
package mycompany.rest.controller

import mycompany.rest.domain.User
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

class PushNotification {    
    companion object {
        val SERVER_KEY = "sOmE_w31rD_F1r3Ba5E-KEy";

        @JvmStatic fun sendPush(user: User, message: String, title: String) {
            if(user.deviceId != "unknown"){
                val pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" +
                title +
                "\",\"message\":\"" +
                message +
                "\"},\"to\":\"" +
                user.deviceId +
                "\"}";


                val url: URL = URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                val conn: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY)
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST")
                conn.setDoOutput(true)

                //send the message content
                val outputStream: OutputStream = conn.getOutputStream()
                outputStream.write(pushMessage.toByteArray())
                println(conn.responseCode)
                println(conn.responseMessage)
            }else {
                println("Nope, not executed")
            }
        }   

        @JvmStatic fun sendPush(users: List<User>, message: String, title: String) {
            for(u in users) {
                PushNotification.sendPush(u, message, title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the method can be called as `PushNotification.sendPush(user1, "Hello world!", "my title");`

**(btw realized you won't need to run the pushnotification from a server (localhost/external). You can just create a main class which sends it with your hardcoded `deviceId` for testing purposes.**

Comment: loved the way u m3nt10n3d k3y , let me try the code

Comment: sorry for late rely was stuck with other ionic stuff, finally i was able to make push notification working with rc3 ... i am running the java code from localhost, what i want to know is how to make call to the java server

push.on('registration', (data) => {
  // call the Java Server ??????? how to do this bit
  let promise: Promise<string> = this.notificationService.push(data.registrationId, 'This is a test message from Ionic Chat');
  promise.then((data) => {

  });
});

Comment: A solution would be to look into Spring, then you can define a url in java (f.e. `localhost:8080/push` ) with your title and message, in the functuon that's called by that url you send the push notification and from ionic you can call it with `this.http.post(url, data, headers?)`

Comment: i am more lost then ever , how are you sending and storing device id ? " this.device_id will later (on succesfull login) be sent to my Kotlin REST API so I know the device_id and have coupled it to a user. "

Comment: I myself am sending it in a `Header` object, this will be sent along with your data and you can retrieve it as `@RequestHeader(value="device_id")` in your API

Comment: would i need to save device tokens ?

Comment: Yes, these are used to identify the different devices and you cannot send a push notification without the device token.

Comment: should i be saving these device tokens to my firebase database or app server ? and one more thing for my requirements i should be using http connection server protocol ? i am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: Personal preference I guess, you will need to store them so probably your database. I don't know anything more about firebase than sending push notifications so I can't help you with that :)

Comment: i am starting to get whats happening , can you tell me how to access this.device_id on my login page, i have called push.on registration on my app.component.ts , i will save the device token generated to my database once the user logs in. but i am not able to access this device id on the login page can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: sorry to bother you again ,  upon login i managed to save device tokens to my firebase database, 
i have my code at https://bitbucket.org/blitzkreig543/solve-buyer
(its public) 
i added the code in app.component.ts
now what i want is to be able to send a push notification whenever the buyer app creates a category job ( src/pages/create-category-job) to the seller from respective category
seller code is here https://blitzkreig543@bitbucket.org/blitzkreig543/solve-seller.git
can you please tell me how to go ahead, any help would be great

Comment: what i want to know is how to call the push.on function on the create job function , i already have import { Push } from native still upon calling the method on the create job page it gives me error .on not valid on push

Comment: i am unable to understand how to publish to a particular topic upon successful job creation

Comment: Ok you need to match a device_id with a buyer or seller. Then when a buyer creates a category job, you will send the topic and id of the seller to your back-end. There you can lookup the seller by id in the database and retrieve the device_id. Then just send a pushnotification to that specific device_id

Comment: thanks for the info i managed to have save token functionality working on my firebase database, but now testing with the plugin https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm , i am stuck with peculiar issue values for my variables are returning null, the value of "token from FcmPlugin function is not getting passed to "deviceId" in ngAfterViewInit, it used to happen so easily earlier, can you just point out issue , the code is at https://blitzkreig543@bitbucket.org/blitzkreig543/solve-buyer.git , in the CODE file in the root directory, please have a look and i might just have it working

Comment: I haven't worked with that plugin so I woulnd't know the issue. Submit a new question explaning your problem.

Comment: i think its a javascript issue , something very obvious that i am missing, been stuck with it for hours

Comment: Then submit a new question on S.O. explaining it and provide some code. Someone will be able to help you out

Comment: please have a look at the CODE file from the repository if you have time, its just that deviceId value fromFcmPlugin function is not passing on to the ngAfterViewInit function

Comment: No problem :) Would look at your code if I had time but don't have any at the moment. Hope you'll fix it though, it's an awesome feature